# Node and sequelize -> .catch(...) isn't working as expected

Tags: node.js, try-catch, sequelize.js

I've got a really simple example here. In this case, 'token' is a read-only property on the model, and throws an error when you try to write it. This is just present to force an error to show how .catch(...) isn't ever being called. The very simple example code is below (name, description, uptime are all variables set to static values before we get to this code):

```
models.TANServer.create({
    name : name,
    description : description,
    defaultUpTime : defaultUpTime,
    token : "apple"
})
.then( function( server ){

    if( !server ){
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.end( "unknown error creating new server entry" );
        return;
    }

    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.end( JSON.stringify( server ) );
    return;

}).catch( function( reason ){
    res.statusCode = 500;
    res.end( "This should print out " + reason + " but is never called as the error stack goes to console, and nothing ever is caught." );
    return;
});
```

The catch is never called, the http request just sits there spinning, and the console output pretty clearly displays that the exception just bubbled up without being caught.

What am I missing about .catch(...) in Sequelize calls?

Thanks.

The pertinent info from the exception stack output follows. The text "This is a read only property" is the error message I generate and toss when you try to write to that property.

```
Unhandled rejection Error: This is a read-only property
```

Comment: There's nothing in here that looks like a write to a read-only property.  Are you sure the rejection error is coming from this code?

Comment: Yes, in my model I'm throwing an exception on writes to that property. I didn't show the model because it's just a super simple model at the moment, and literally has a name, description, the uptime and the token properties. Token is generated in the model when a new record is generated, and lives in that record forever as a read-only value, akin to db id. Specifically, it's just a UUID. To be fair/clear, I could easily remove it and just use the record id, but that wouldn't really change the issue I'm having.

Comment: In short, shouldn't *ANY* exception generated calling TANServer.Create({...}) bubble out to the .catch(...) block as listed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `.catch` only catches issues thrown *in the promise resolution handler* (that is, the function passed to `.then` in your example).

Looking at the comments, it appears that the line throwing the error is:

```
models.TANServer.create({
  name : name,
  description : description,
  defaultUpTime : defaultUpTime,
  token : "apple"
})
```

If that is the case, then no promise is returned, and so the `.then` and `.catch` expressions are never run, and no response is returned.

The fix is to change `.create` so it returns a failed promise (using `Promise.reject`) rather than throwing an error

#### What if I can't fix `.create`?

If `.create` is third-party code, or if you need synchronous errors most of the time, but this one case is painful you can wrap the call to create in a `try / catch` statement or a `Promise.resolve` block:

```
try {
  models.TANServer.create(...).then(...).catch(...);
catch (e) {
  // A synchronous exception happened here
}

// Alternatively (and much better IMO):
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  // Any synchronous errors here will fail the promise chain
  // triggering the .catch
  return models.TANServer.create(...);
}).then(server => {
  // Use server here
}).catch(reason => {
  // All errors show up here
});
```

Comment: Makes an odd bit of sense. Thanks. The .Create is absolutely under my control, so I can do that. Thanks much! Appreciate it. The Sequelize docs are, IMO, a bit lacking for certain bits of clarity. I'm not sure I read anything quite so succinct and direct as you pointed out in hours of reading, testing, recoding, experimenting, etc. Thanks, man!